# On Euler angles decomposition of $\mathrm{SU}(N)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, manifolds

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$I am looking for a (generalized) Euler angles decomposition for $\SU(N)\ (N>1)$ in the following fashion:
$$
\SU(N)\ni m = a\, u \, b
$$
where $a,b$ are independent diagonal $\SU(N)$-matrices each of which accounts for $N-1$ parameters
while $u\in \SU(N)$ is parametrized by the remain $(N-1)^2$ parameters. For instance the matrices $u$ might form a $U(N)$-isomorphic subgroup of $\SU(N)$. Notice that in the case $N=2$ this decomposition reduces to the known Euler's one $a(b)= \exp(i \alpha(\beta) \sigma_3)$ and $U = \exp(i \gamma \sigma_2)$ where $\sigma_j$ is a Pauli matrix and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are the angles.

I found in literature [Bertini, Cacciatori, and Cerchiai - On the Euler angles for $\operatorname{SU}(N)$](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2190898) and [Tilma and Sudarshan - Generalized Euler angle parametrization for $\operatorname{SU}(N)$](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/35/48/316/meta) other kinds of generalizations of Euler angles decompositions, however they differ in form from the one above.

Can you point me to some relevant literature? Can you show me a working parametrization of $u$ such that the whole $\SU(N)$ is covered?

Comment: You might be interested in [“Sinkhorn normal form for unitary matrices”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5728)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the paper [Idel and Wolf - Sinkhorn normal form for unitary matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5728) Colin McQuillan [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430835/on-euler-angles-decomposition-of-mathrmsun#comment1108718_430835), it is easy to see that every $\operatorname{SU}(N)$ matrix $m$ can be decomposed as

$$
m = a \,u\, b 
$$
with $a,b \in \operatorname{SU}(N)$ and diagonal, and
$$
u = F \,\left(\frac{1}{\mathrm{det}(V)} \oplus V\right) F^\dagger  \in \operatorname{SU}(N)
$$

where $F_{jk} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}jk}$ is the Fourier transform unitary matrix and $V\in \operatorname{U}(N-1)$.

Notice that the number of parameters of this factorization matches the dimension of $\operatorname{SU}(N)$.

Comment: I thought the question asked for diagonal $a,b$ ?

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker. Sure a and b are diagonal, I forgot to mention it in the answer. I made an edit about it.